# Passing a string in java into batch file for some other purposes

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd, command

I am currently finding ways to pass a string in java to a batch file where several commands will be running based on it.

For example..

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    JButton btnSelect = new JButton("SELECT");
    btnSelect.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent args) 
        {

            //chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true); //enable multiple selection of files
            int i = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

            if (i == chooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
            {
                textField.setText(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
            }

            //works. able to output file path.
            //System.out.println(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
        }
    });
//when start button is selected
    btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent args)
        {
            // image info code
            try
            {   
                //System.out.println(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
                //create new process
                String command = "cmd /c start /wait "+DetectDrive+"\\imageinfo.bat";
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

                //cause this process to stop until process p is terminated
                p.waitFor();
            } 
            catch (IOException | InterruptedException e1)
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

So this is part of my java coding. But what I want is that when the user uses the "select" option to choose a file, this file path is `System.out.println(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());`.

How can I pass this parameter to a batch file for other uses? Because my batch file will need the filepath chose by the user.

I heard there's a way but I do not know how.. I tried researching but didn't seem to work. Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

**EDITED**

I have written this to my java coding:

```
String filePath = chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
//create new process
String command = "cmd /c start /wait "+DetectDrive+"\\BatchFiles\\imageinfo.bat";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{command,"\""+filePath+"\""});
p.waitFor();
```

When a user selects a file (e.g. E:\jooo.txt), the `filePath` is able to store that file path.
But when I run it, there's seems something wrong with the `Process p = ...`

And I do not know what to write to my batch file so that the file path that the user has selected will be shown in the batch file.

For example (**In my batch file**):

```
echo %filePath%
```

It doesn't seems to work. How should I code in the batch file so that it will show the file path that the user has selected in java?

I'm new to this area so I need more help here. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**EDITED2**

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd /c start /wait E:\\imageinfo.bat": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at Volatility$3.actionPerformed(Volatility.java:187)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    ...
```

This is my error. I am trying to debug now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String[] command = 
new String[]{"cmd", "/c", "start", "/wait",
             DetectDrive+"\\imageinfo.bat", fileToPath};
```

Borrowed the answer shamelessly from another website.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you just need to call `exec(String[])` with the array being the command and its parameters.

Thus your call might look like this:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{ command, pathToFile });
```

Note that you might have to wrap the path in double quotes for Windows to correctly handle paths which contain spaces or other special characters.

**Update**:

`echo %filePath%` would only work if you have a variable in your batch file which is called `filePath`. Note that you can't access Java variables from batch files.

If you pass a parameter to a batch file it will most likely make them accessible through their index, e.g. `echo %1` would print the value of the first parameter (which should be the file's path in your case).

Comment: @Steven almost, I meant something like `"\"" + chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath() + "\""` to pass the path to the process.

Comment: hmm... I wished I have understood. When I tried but it has errors. What does the "\" is for? So `chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath()` saves a filepath e.g. F:\Document.doc and then I can just `set /P p=chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath()` in my batch file???

Comment: @Steven no, using `p=chooser...` would create a parameter with exactly that name. You need to use the string that represents the path, i.e. the return value of `chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath()` and since a path _might_ contain spaces you _might_ need to add double quotes to that string at the start and the end, that's what the `"\""` is for - it's a string literal containing a single double quote.

Comment: ok.. but when i put `Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{command,"\""+filePath+"\""});`, this sentence seems to give me error. and i don't understand.

Comment: @Steven well, you should describe what error your get as well as test/debug what is happening. As I said it _should_ work this way but maybe process execution doesn't like your command (which could be an error with syntax, environment etc.), so you might want to test that with a hard coded path first.

Comment: here's what my error is. Ok, noted. I am also trying to debug now.